# Kerberros GSSAPI doesn't work within kafkacat alpine container

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, sasl, gssapi, kcat

Previously I've reported it into [`kafkacat` tracker](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/issues/319) but the issue has been closed as related to `cyrus-sasl`/`krb5`.

```sh
podman run --rm -it --name kafkacat-DEV \
        -v$(pwd)/conf/integration:/conf -v$(pwd)/conf/integration/krb5.conf:/etc/krb5.conf \
        localhost/kafkacat_gssapi:1 \
                kafkacat \
                        -b kafka-int.example.com:9095 \
                                -Xssl.ca.location=/conf/kafka-int.ca.crt \
                                -Xsecurity.protocol=SASL_SSL \
                                -Xsasl.mechanisms=GSSAPI \
                                '-Xsasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd=cat /conf/paswd | /usr/bin/kinit Pavel_Alexeev@EXAMPLE.COM' \
                                -Xsasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka \
                                        -m30 -L
```

Error:

```
Password for Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM: 
%5|1620820968.991|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%2|1620820969.336|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found)
%3|1620820969.336|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: Failed to initialize SASL authentication: SASL handshake failed (start (-1)): SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found) (after 345ms in state AUTH_REQ)
%5|1620820970.006|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%2|1620820970.137|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found)
%3|1620820970.137|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: Failed to initialize SASL authentication: SASL handshake failed (start (-1)): SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found) (after 131ms in state AUTH_REQ, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%5|1620820971.431|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%2|1620820972.935|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found)
%5|1620820976.319|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%2|1620820976.745|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found)
%5|1620820987.183|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%2|1620820987.651|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found)
%5|1620820998.114|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%2|1620820998.480|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found)
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure
```

Where `localhost/kafkacat_gssapi:1` just built from `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker.io/edenhill/kafkacat:1.6.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
RUN apk add --no-cache cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-gssapiv2 krb5 openssl ca-certificates
```

```sh
$ podman run -it --rm localhost/kafkacat_gssapi:1 -V
kafkacat - Apache Kafka producer and consumer tool
https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat
Copyright (c) 2014-2019, Magnus Edenhill
Version 1.6.0 (JSON, Avro, Transactions, librdkafka 1.5.0 builtin.features=gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer)
```

Same run on Fedora 33:

```sh
kafkacat \
        -b kafka-int.example.com:9095 \
        -Xssl.ca.location=conf/integration/kafka-int.ca.crt \
        -Xsecurity.protocol=SASL_SSL \
        -Xsasl.mechanisms=GSSAPI \
        '-Xsasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd=cat conf/paswd | /usr/bin/kinit Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM' \
        -Xsasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka \
        -m 30 \
        -L
```

```
Password for Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM: 
%5|1620821374.957|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%5|1620821384.957|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%5|1620821385.027|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 2
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap):
 3 brokers:
  broker 202 at ecsc00a09eab.example.com:9095
  broker 201 at ecsc00a09eaa.example.com:9095 (controller)
  broker 203 at ecsc00a09eac.example.com:9095
 1440 topics:
  topic "test-topic" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 202, replicas: 202,203,201, isrs: 201,203,202
  topic "datahub.....EffectiveFrom" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 201, replicas: 201,203, isrs: 201,203
...
```

What interesting, if I run with `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout` in direct working case I see ([full log](https://paste.centos.org/view/560ca9f0)):

```
[2616356] 1620807906.324107: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616356] 1620807906.324108: No URI records found
[2616356] 1620807906.324109: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos._tcp.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616356] 1620807906.324110: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evrupetsa0001.petersburg.example.com."
[2616356] 1620807906.324111: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evrupetsa0007.petersburg.example.com."
[2616356] 1620807906.324112: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evbyminsa0007.petersburg.example.com."
[2616356] 1620807906.324113: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evusprisa0049.petersburg.example.com."
[2616356] 1620807906.324114: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evhubudsa0001.petersburg.example.com."
[2616356] 1620807906.324115: Resolving hostname evrupetsa0001.petersburg.example.com.
[2616356] 1620807906.324116: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.66.110.11:88
[2616356] 1620807906.324117: Sending TCP request to stream 10.66.110.11:88
[2616356] 1620807906.324118: Received answer (4491 bytes) from stream 10.66.110.11:88
[2616356] 1620807906.324119: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.66.110.11:88
[2616356] 1620807906.324120: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616356] 1620807906.324121: No URI records found
[2616356] 1620807906.324122: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos-master._tcp.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616356] 1620807906.324123: No SRV records found
[2616356] 1620807906.324124: Response was not from master KDC
[2616356] 1620807906.324125: Processing preauth types: PA-ETYPE-INFO2 (19)
[2616356] 1620807906.324126: Selected etype info: etype aes256-cts, salt "PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COMPavel_Alexeev", params ""
[2616356] 1620807906.324127: Produced preauth for next request: (empty)
[2616356] 1620807906.324128: AS key determined by preauth: aes256-cts/83C9
[2616356] 1620807906.324129: Decrypted AS reply; session key is: aes256-cts/CCEB
[2616356] 1620807906.324130: FAST negotiation: unavailable
[2616356] 1620807906.324131: Initializing FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000 with default princ Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
[2616356] 1620807906.324132: Storing Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM in FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
[2616356] 1620807906.324133: Storing config in FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000 for krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM: pa_type: 2
[2616356] 1620807906.324134: Storing Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krb5_ccache_conf_data/pa_type/krbtgt\/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM\@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@X-CACHECONF: in FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
%5|1620807906.993|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
[2616353] 1620807906.996539: ccselect can't find appropriate cache for server principal kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
[2616353] 1620807906.996540: Getting credentials Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM using ccache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
[2616353] 1620807906.996541: Retrieving Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM from FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000 with result: -1765328243/Matching credential not found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1000)
[2616353] 1620807906.996542: Retrieving Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM from FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000 with result: -1765328243/Matching credential not found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1000)
[2616353] 1620807906.996543: Retrieving Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM from FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000 with result: 0/Success
[2616353] 1620807906.996544: Starting with TGT for client realm: Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
[2616353] 1620807906.996545: Retrieving Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM from FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000 with result: -1765328243/Matching credential not found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1000)
[2616353] 1620807906.996546: Requesting TGT krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM using TGT krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
[2616353] 1620807906.996547: Generated subkey for TGS request: aes256-cts/69EE
[2616353] 1620807906.996548: etypes requested in TGS request: aes256-cts, aes128-cts, aes256-sha2, aes128-sha2, rc4-hmac, camellia128-cts, camellia256-cts
[2616353] 1620807906.996550: Encoding request body and padata into FAST request
[2616353] 1620807906.996551: Sending request (4611 bytes) to PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
[2616353] 1620807906.996552: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807907.003430: No URI records found
[2616353] 1620807907.003431: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos._udp.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807907.003432: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evrupetsa0007.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003433: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evrupetsa0001.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003434: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evusprisa0049.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003435: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evhubudsa0001.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003436: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evbyminsa0007.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003437: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos._tcp.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807907.003438: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evrupetsa0007.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003439: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evbyminsa0007.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003440: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evusprisa0049.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003441: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evhubudsa0001.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003442: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evrupetsa0001.petersburg.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003443: Resolving hostname evrupetsa0007.petersburg.example.com.
[2616353] 1620807907.003444: Resolving hostname evrupetsa0001.petersburg.example.com.
[2616353] 1620807907.003445: Resolving hostname evusprisa0049.petersburg.example.com.
[2616353] 1620807907.003446: Resolving hostname evhubudsa0001.petersburg.example.com.
[2616353] 1620807907.003447: Resolving hostname evbyminsa0007.petersburg.example.com.
[2616353] 1620807907.003448: Resolving hostname evrupetsa0007.petersburg.example.com.
[2616353] 1620807907.003449: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.66.110.17:88
[2616353] 1620807907.003450: Sending TCP request to stream 10.66.110.17:88
[2616353] 1620807907.003451: Received answer (4542 bytes) from stream 10.66.110.17:88
[2616353] 1620807907.003452: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.66.110.17:88
[2616353] 1620807907.003453: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807907.003454: No URI records found
[2616353] 1620807907.003455: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos-master._tcp.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807907.003456: No SRV records found
[2616353] 1620807907.003457: Response was not from master KDC
[2616353] 1620807907.003458: Decoding FAST response
[2616353] 1620807907.003459: FAST reply key: aes256-cts/9007
[2616353] 1620807907.003460: TGS reply is for Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM with session key rc4-hmac/7459
[2616353] 1620807907.003461: TGS request result: 0/Success
[2616353] 1620807907.003462: Storing Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM in FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
[2616353] 1620807907.003463: Received TGT for service realm: krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
[2616353] 1620807907.003464: Requesting tickets for kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM, referrals on
[2616353] 1620807907.003465: Generated subkey for TGS request: rc4-hmac/F9B4
[2616353] 1620807907.003466: etypes requested in TGS request: aes256-cts, aes128-cts, aes256-sha2, aes128-sha2, rc4-hmac, camellia128-cts, camellia256-cts
[2616353] 1620807907.003468: Encoding request body and padata into FAST request
[2616353] 1620807907.003469: Sending request (4615 bytes) to EXAMPLE.COM
[2616353] 1620807907.003470: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807907.003471: No URI records found
[2616353] 1620807907.003472: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos._udp.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807907.003473: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evusbossa0000.example.com."
[2616353] 1620807907.003474: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evkzastsa0000.example.com."
...
[2616353] 1620807907.003762: Resolving hostname EVUAVINSA0000.example.com.
[2616353] 1620807907.003763: Resolving hostname EVUSCONSA0000.example.com.
[2616353] 1620807907.003764: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.22.128.2:88
[2616353] 1620807907.003765: Sending TCP request to stream 10.22.128.2:88
[2616353] 1620807908.732538: Received answer (4631 bytes) from stream 10.22.128.2:88
[2616353] 1620807908.732539: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.22.128.2:88
[2616353] 1620807908.732540: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807908.732541: No URI records found
[2616353] 1620807908.732542: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos-master._tcp.EXAMPLE.COM.
[2616353] 1620807908.732543: No SRV records found
[2616353] 1620807908.732544: Response was not from master KDC
[2616353] 1620807908.732545: Decoding FAST response
[2616353] 1620807908.732546: FAST reply key: rc4-hmac/2A6B
[2616353] 1620807908.732547: TGS reply is for Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM with session key aes256-cts/F35A
[2616353] 1620807908.732548: TGS request result: 0/Success
[2616353] 1620807908.732549: Received creds for desired service kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
[2616353] 1620807908.732550: Storing Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM in FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
[2616353] 1620807908.732552: Creating authenticator for Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM, seqnum 691537013, subkey aes256-cts/A6FD, session key aes256-cts/F35A
%5|1620807908.873|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
```

In case of an error in the alpine container ([full log](https://paste.centos.org/view/bbe58142)):

```
[4] 1620808362.090471: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[4] 1620808362.090472: No URI records found
[4] 1620808362.090473: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos._tcp.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[4] 1620808362.090474: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evusprisa0049.petersburg.example.com."
[4] 1620808362.090475: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evhubudsa0001.petersburg.example.com."
[4] 1620808362.090476: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evrupetsa0001.petersburg.example.com."
[4] 1620808362.090477: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evrupetsa0007.petersburg.example.com."
[4] 1620808362.090478: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "evbyminsa0007.petersburg.example.com."
[4] 1620808362.090479: Resolving hostname evusprisa0049.petersburg.example.com.
[4] 1620808362.090480: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.244.110.7:88
[4] 1620808362.090481: Sending TCP request to stream 10.244.110.7:88
[4] 1620808362.090482: Received answer (4491 bytes) from stream 10.244.110.7:88
[4] 1620808362.090483: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.244.110.7:88
[4] 1620808362.090484: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[4] 1620808362.090485: No URI records found
[4] 1620808362.090486: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos-master._tcp.PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM.
[4] 1620808362.090487: No SRV records found
[4] 1620808362.090488: Response was not from master KDC
[4] 1620808362.090489: Processing preauth types: PA-ETYPE-INFO2 (19)
[4] 1620808362.090490: Selected etype info: etype aes256-cts, salt "PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COMPavel_Alexeev", params ""
[4] 1620808362.090491: Produced preauth for next request: (empty)
[4] 1620808362.090492: AS key determined by preauth: aes256-cts/83C9
[4] 1620808362.090493: Decrypted AS reply; session key is: aes256-cts/9506
[4] 1620808362.090494: FAST negotiation: unavailable
[4] 1620808362.090495: Initializing FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0 with default princ Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
[4] 1620808362.090496: Storing Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM in FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
[4] 1620808362.090497: Storing config in FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0 for krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM: pa_type: 2
[4] 1620808362.090498: Storing Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM -> krb5_ccache_conf_data/pa_type/krbtgt\/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM\@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@X-CACHECONF: in FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
%5|1620808363.004|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI client step 1
%2|1620808363.250|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://kafka-int.example.com:9095/bootstrap: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Matching credential (kafka/ecsc00a09ead.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) not found)
```

What also looks very interesting and strange to me, on host machine where all works just after `kafkacat` execution klist show me 3 tickets:

```sh
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
12/05/21 19:53:26  13/05/21 03:53:26  krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 19/05/21 19:53:26
12/05/21 19:53:27  13/05/21 03:53:26  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 19/05/21 19:53:26
12/05/21 19:53:28  13/05/21 03:53:26  kafka/kafka-int.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 13/05/21 05:53:28
```

But in the same time, if I change parameter '-Xsasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd=/usr/bin/kinit --use-referrals --password-file=/conf/paswd Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM; klist' I see there only one ticket! For example:

```sh
$ podman run --rm -it --name kafkacat-DEV \
        -v$(pwd)/conf/integration:/conf -v$(pwd)/conf/integration/krb5.conf:/etc/krb5.conf \
        localhost/kafkacat_gssapi_heimdal:3 \
                kafkacat \
                        -b kafka-int.example.com:9095 \
                                -Xssl.ca.location=/conf/kafka-int.ca.crt \
                                -Xsecurity.protocol=SASL_SSL \
                                -Xsasl.mechanisms=GSSAPI \
                                '-Xsasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd=/usr/bin/kinit --use-referrals --password-file=/conf/paswd Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM; klist' \
                                -Xsasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka \
                                        -m30 -L
...
Credentials cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
        Principal: Pavel_Alexeev@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
May 12 18:54:50 2021  May 13 02:54:49 2021  krbtgt/PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM@PETERSBURG.EXAMPLE.COM
...
```

**So I can't understand where 2 others come from**

Listing after execute `kafkacat` in the container also show only a single principal.

Will appreciate any help.

P.S. Also report it as [`cyrus-sasl` issue](https://github.com/cyrusimap/cyrus-sasl/issues/649)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange issue, and honestly I can't say why, but adding into `krb5.conf`:

```
[libdefaults]
dns_canonicalize_hostname = false
```

solves the problem.

P.S. I've posted that as the solution because it starts work. But if someone may explain in comments why it is the solution and especially how that may be understandable from provided logs it will be very helpful.